# Start/stop script to refresh the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<html>
<head>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {

setTimeout(function() { window.location.reload(); }, 2000); // 2 seconds, e.g.


});
</script>

<script>
    $("#siteloader")
        .html('<object data="http://www.mysite.co.uk"/>');
</script>


</head>
<body>
<div> 
<object type="text/html" data="http://www.mysite.co.uk" width="800px" height="600px" style="overflow:auto;border:5px ridge blue">
</object>
</body>
</html>
```

I have the above code which loads a site into a div, and refreshes the page every 2 seconds. I'd like a button which stops/starts the refresh function. I've tried a few different methods but none seem to work. I have very little javascript knowledge so I'm hoping my coding isn't too bad!

Comment: Why are you reloading the entire page instead of refreshing the required part(s) of it?

Comment: I'm new to javascript, certainly reloading the div containing the external site would be more efficient, but I'm not that advanced just yet :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var timeout;
$(document).ready(function () {
  timeout = setTimeout(function() { window.location.reload(); }, 2000); // 2 seconds, e.g.
  $("#siteloader").html('<object data="http://www.mysite.co.uk"/>');
});

function stopReload() {
  clearTimeout(timeout);
}

</script>
```

Further you may add a button or anything like this to stop the timeout like this:

```
<a onclick="stopReload();">Stop it!</a>
```

---

EDIT:

To start it again change the code like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var timeout;
$(document).ready(function () {
  startReload(); //NEW PART
  $("#siteloader").html('<object data="http://www.mysite.co.uk"/>');
});

function stopReload() {
  clearTimeout(timeout);
}
function startReload() {
  timeout = setTimeout(function() { window.location.reload(); }, 2000); // 2 seconds, e.g.
}

</script>
```

And add another button:

```
<a onclick="startReload();">Start it!</a>
```

Comment: Excellent, thanks for the code help, just what I needed :) Do you have any idea how to start the function again? My js knowledge isn't cutting it at the moment :(

Answer (score 0):

`setTimeout` has a return value which you can use to stop the timer. http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_cleartimeout.asp There's even an example on this page, which does exactly what you need.

Comment: While true, this is more of a comment at the moment. You need to complete your answer with a code example of what you mean (applied to the question asked).

Comment: Follow the link... And, I don't *need* to complete the answer with a code example. Anything that helps to resolve the problem is certainly welcome.

Comment: In that case this suggestion should be made as a comment. Not my DV BTW.

Comment: [w3schools is an awful resource](http://www.w3fools.com/) you'd be better linkeing to the [MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers.setTimeout)

Comment: Thanks, I'm trying to integrate this coding into my current code, struggling at the moment but I'm sure I'll get there, thanks.